# Бесконечное требование о завершении регистрации в Stack Overflow

Tags: stackoverflow

Зарегистрировался здесь, нажимаю на кнопку "Завершить регистрацию" в правом верхнем углу, ввожу почту, пароль, прохожу капчу, запрашиваю регистрацию. Далее меня выбрасывает в главное меню, снова выплывает требование завершить регистрацию.
Пробовал регистрироваться и через Facebook, и через Яндекс, но ситуация не изменилась.

Заранее благодарю

P.S. Использую эту тему, а не мету, т.к. для публикации в мете нужна завершённая регистрация. Иронично...

Comment: Сотрите куки или откройте анонимную сессию в браузере.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, пробовал, ничего не изменилось

Comment: Почту смотрели? Письмо с кодом подтверждения не попало в спам?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, уже подтверждал по ссылке, которая пришла на почту, новых писем нет (кроме рассылки)